# Mongo-Db mapReduce options types understanding

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to understand types for mapReduce function, there we have this types for `mapReduceOptions` (also, I know this is depreciated)

```
export interface MapReduceOptions<TKey = ObjectId, TValue = Document>
  extends CommandOperationOptions {
  /** Sets the output target for the map reduce job. */
  out?: 'inline' | { inline: 1 } | { replace: string } | { merge: string } | { reduce: string };
  /** Query filter object. */
  query?: Document;
  /** Sorts the input objects using this key. Useful for optimization, like sorting by the emit key for fewer reduces. */
  sort?: Sort;
  /** Number of objects to return from collection. */
  limit?: number;
  /** Keep temporary data. */
  keeptemp?: boolean;
  /** Finalize function. */
  finalize?: FinalizeFunction<TKey, TValue> | string;
  /** Can pass in variables that can be access from map/reduce/finalize. */
  scope?: Document;
  /** It is possible to make the execution stay in JS. Provided in MongoDB \> 2.0.X. */
  jsMode?: boolean;
  /** Provide statistics on job execution time. */
  verbose?: boolean;
  /** Allow driver to bypass schema validation in MongoDB 3.2 or higher. */
  bypassDocumentValidation?: boolean;
}
```

Reference in the code here:https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4.1/src/operations/map_reduce.ts#L50

Now, From the examples I have seen, all of them have `out` so first why is this `optional`, like what happens if we don't specify optional and second, shouldn't this be a `string` instead of `inline`?

```
out?: 'inline' | { inline: 1 } | { replace: string } | { merge: string } | { reduce: string };
```

Like don't people use it like this?

```
mapReduce(
function(){ emit(this.Name,1)},
function(key, values) {return Array.sum(values)},
{query:{Marks:{$gt:70}},out: 'Name_Total'}).
```

Comment: Do you really try to **understand** the `mapReduce` function or do you try to re-implement an outdated function in your application? Why do you waste time on this?

Answer (score 0):

The `out` field may be optional when building an options object, which allows you to add one field at a time if you want.  It is required by the underlying [mapReduce](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce) database command, so it must exist prior to submitting the command.

The out option will not accept any random string.  The pipe symbol `|` is a logical or in this type construction:

```
'inline' | { inline: 1 } | { replace: string } | { merge: string } | { reduce: string }
```

This means it can be the explicit string 'inline' or the explicit object `{inline: 1}`, or an object containing a single field whose name 'replace', 'merge', or 'reduce' and whose value is a string.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I didn't get it. **The map option will not accept any random string** These `out?: 'inline' | { inline: 1 } | { replace: string } | { merge: string } | { reduce: string };` are the types for `out`? and not `map`?

Comment: **The out field may be optional when building an options object** and then this **It is required by the underlying mapReduce database command, so it must exist prior to submitting the command.**. If it is required by database command then how could it be optional? Also `out` also takes `string` value. I can't seem to find type for it.

Comment: Both MongoDB and TypeScript can define optional.  Making it optional in the type allows you can initially create the object without that field, and add it later, without causing an error.  It is still non-optional in MongoDB, so if you submit it to the database without adding that field, it will return an error.